# Different capacity lithium-ion batteries in parallel

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, bms, lithium-polymer

Is there any problem if I put different capacity,from different manufacturer with different specification? This is my current configuration:[image: Configuration]

DW01 Protection Bord is being used on both. But power bank circuit also contains protection circuit.

Comment: If you add a charge controller AND an undervoltage protector to each battery then you may be able to achieve a workable result. Similar to a TP4056 with DW01 per battery. How many cells per battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer yes, it is a problem... the weaker battery will start causing damage on the better one. it will cause current flow from one to the other battery and in best case you will suffer early degradation of both batteries.

---

Edit

combine two packs by two diodes

[image: simple solution]

This is the solution with only one pack at a time

[image: complex solution]

circuit diagram

[image: circuit]

This one I collected some 10-15 years ago from a model plane magazine,
hope you get the idea

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to use both cells?

Comment: RC model plane builders use circuits to switch from the main to a backup battery if the main gets too week. You may try just do add a diode to each pack, but they consume a certain amount of the stored energy and get hot with larger currents

Comment: I just added some more info to the answer

Comment: Thanks @schedan 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are problems.

As schhnendan mentioned different capacity is big problem but even if they are same capacity and different manufacturer that is huge problem. For life of product and for safety of product.

It seems you are planning to use this as power bank. As you will use it for longer time the battery with slight worse chemistry will start degrading and a better battery will try to charge worse battery.

It seems you have DW01 but you do not have temperature control. Both of your batteries will drain at different C ratings, generating different temperature further degrading the battery.

Worst of all how will you charge your power bank? Current control and Li-Po charge profile is controlled by the off-the-shelf charging ICs. But as IC tries to charge two batteries in parallel, actual current charging the battery is not same as what Charging IC considers it is. So both batteries will charge with incorrect charge profile.

Also, you can not get away without using temperature control for charging of lipo batteries if they are anywhere above 200mAh. Its just too risky. Now if you decide to use temperature control how will you do it because most charger IC will not be able to interface with two thermistors.

Comment: Thanks @Curius KP for the answer. First, my main power bank circuit contains all kind of protections and features including thermistors. It is a original xiaomi power bank circuit which I bought from a supplier in local market. This circuits uses more then capable IC's from reputable brands and uses high quality components.

Comment: but does it use two batteries in parallel in original product or single battery.
If battery gets changed then circuit is not accurate anymore.